# Certain code to block ads from showing on a page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

A few years ago I had some code i could insert into a page and it would block any adsense ads or other ads from showing. I can no longer find what I had used, but one thing i'm sure is I wasn't using any type of ad blocking software or extensions..

i wrote this code:

```
    <?php // START SHOW_ADSENSE
    defined("SHOW_ADSENSE") || define("SHOW_ADSENSE", 1);
    if (SHOW_ADSENSE){
    ?>

    <script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
        data-ad-client="ca-publisher-id"
        data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
    <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>

    <?php } // END SHOW_ADSENSE ?>

<?php defined("SHOW_ADSENSE") || define("SHOW_ADSENSE", 0); ?>
```

but is there a simpler way and block all ads at once ?

Comment: If you control the server-side code, why can't you prevent the ads from being shown in the first place?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, why would you want to prevent the thing that makes you money from showing on your own site?